# Pymongo find array element into collection

Tags: python, json, mongodb

i have develop python function to find all element by collection into mongodb, this is my code

```
def get_all_beacon():
    beacon = mongo.db.beacon_ss
    output = []
    for s in beacon.find():
    output.append({'Lon' : s['x'], 'Lat' : s['y']})
    return jsonify({'result' : output})
```

but i use this code when i have a simple structure of `json collection`.
Now i have this `json` structure into collection:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
  {
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":{
        "Id":0,
        "IDENTIFICA":"981"
     },
     "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
           12.495219988267976,
           41.86792598901761
        ]
     }
  },
  {
     "type":"Feature",
     "properties":{
        "Id":0,
        "IDENTIFICA":"983"
     },
     "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
           12.495215710032879,
           41.86785696880555
        ]
     }
  }]}
```

in this case how i can take the coordinate value?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "take?"   Do you just want to query the entire collection and return JUST the lon and lat coords?

Comment: Yes. I need this